# Block Declaration and Definition is confusion iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

Can somebody please explain to me i need to separate out the declaration and definition of block like given below:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// Main method
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {       
       NSLog(@"Hello, World!");            
    }
}

// Working fine. This code is working fine 
- (void) blockSample{

    (void) (^myBLock) (id sender);

    myBlock = ^(id sender){    // It working fine.
        //implementation
    }
    return 0;
}
/* I need it most work like this.*/
// it shows me error
(void) (^myBLock) (id sender);

myBlock = ^(id sender){    // It shows me error of redefinition.
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: Your goal is to return a block from a method, where the block has a typedef?

Comment: No just to declare it at start of the class and define at end of the class. Just like a function in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a type when defining a variable outside of a function. You can achieve that by first defining a type for your block, or declaring and defining the block in one line.

This works for me:

MyClass.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (void)myMethod;
@end
```

MyClass.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"

typedef void (^MyBlockType) (id sender);
MyBlockType myBlock = ^(id sender) {
    NSLog(@"It works!");
};

@implementation MyClass
- (void)myMethod {
    myBlock(nil);
}

@end
```

Then, elsewhere...

```
MyClass *myClass = [MyClass new];
[myClass myMethod]; // Prints "It works!"
```

I recommend you read [Declaring and Creating Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1) in the Blocks Programming Topics.

Comment: Sorry for that it is type mistake not in actual code. It is giving the same error.

Comment: I tried it and it works with no errors. What does your header file look like? That redefinition error you're seeing makes me believe you've already defined myBlock somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks For the solution. This also works for me. But i need declaration and definition outside of a method.In your code You have also declare and define in a same method.

Comment: @Techie See my update. You can move the declaration outside the method, it should still work.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes i need both declaration and defination both outside the 'my Method' and then refer it to multiple places? Can we do that like in my example i need definition myBlock = ^(id sender){
    //implementation
} outside the class.

Comment: Thanks Nebs I understand what you are talking about. But i did not get where is the mistake in my code that is if i can define it in some method then why not outside of class?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should work now based on your example.

Comment: "I think if you want to define a standard C variable for your block, you need to provide a type. You can do this with a typedef for your block." Typedefs are never "needed". They are just syntactic sugar. Anything written with a typedef can be converted to the equivalent without typedefs, by expanding the typedef.

Comment: @newacct You're correct, I've updated that line in the my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`someVar = someValue;` is an assignment statement. Statements are not allowed outside of functions in C. Only definitions are allowed outside of functions. Thus it is a syntax error.

Like

```
int foo;
foo = 5;
```

is equally not valid outside of functions.

What you really want to do is initialize the variable when defining it:

```
void (^myBLock) (id sender) = ^(id sender) {    // It shows me error of redefinition.
    //implementation
};
```